# react native app auth plugin network error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I tried to create a react native app with OAuth login in my rails app.

I have this react native setup

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'http://app.domain.tld',
  clientId: '85bb84b9cb0528b1f64b7c77586507b3ca5e69b11abe36ae1e54e88a6150c21e',
  clientSecret: '0d3c0713437e0028a121a0c2294cc9a72f4eb5609416935a2860e20f176c7855',
  redirectUrl: 'com.domain://com.domain',
  responseType: 'code',
  scopes: [],
  dangerouslyAllowInsecureHttpRequests: __DEV__,
  // clientAuthMethod: 'post',
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'http://app.domain.tld/oauth/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: 'http://app.domain.tld/oauth/token',
    // revocationEndpoint: 'http://app.domain.tld/oauth/revoke'
  },
  additionalParameters: {
    approval_prompt: 'force'
  }

}

// use the client to make the auth request and receive the authState
try {
  const result = await authorize(config)
  // result includes accessToken, accessTokenExpirationDate and refreshToken
  console.log('result', result)
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', error.message)
}
```

the oaut app looks like this:
[image]

When I press the button to login in my app, I get a browser window where I can login in my rails app and got redirected to the authorize page for the oauth app. After I authorize my app, I got redirected to the app with the message "Network error". With that message I can't find out whats wrong, maybe anyone can help me.

In the server logs I can see this:

```
Redirected to com.domain://com.domain?code=54f3b4c03ea3724522f9a7983e2ea1b9037336076cd52cb875f9654d5d79784a&state=8xmiicVcPKN980ZDZUwBnw
```

in the debugger-ui i get this error log:

```
error Error: Network error
    at createErrorFromErrorData (ReactNativeART.js:10)
    at ActivityIndicator.js:72
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (ReactNativeART.js:472)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/1fccf34b-97b0-4c42-81fa-f0e1391a3ad3:2358
    at MessageQueue.__guard (ReactNativeART.js:373)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/1fccf34b-97b0-4c42-81fa-f0e1391a3ad3:2357)
    at debuggerWorker.js:80
```

so i think there is something wrong. The app didn't make any further request to the server to obtain the access_token. Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in config:

```
dangerouslyAllowInsecureHttpRequests: true,
```